# mPDF images not showing on live server

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

We are using mPDF to generating report pdf files from an html page containing a small png image.

All is tested and working on the local server and was working on the live server until a couple of days ago.

Now where the image should be is just a small red X.

We have run some tests and discovered the following:

1. The images can be accessed through the browser.
2. Images will show in the pdf if the src attribute is pointing to an image on a different website.

We are using the newest version of mPDF, with php and a linux server.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You need to show your code...

Answer (score 2):

You have to install PHP GD Library on your live server

Answer (score 2):

Try using an absolute path for the images:

```
<img src="domain.com/images/logo.png" />
```

instead of relative, even if your relative definition starts with the root of your "web" directory:

```
<img src="/images/logo.png" />
```

In my experience, mpdf doesn't understand well non-absolute paths for images. The web browser however, doesn't seem to have any problem with it and shows fine.

Comment: In my case changing absolute path to relative path worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was on it for 4 hours, locally the image worked fine but on amazon ec2 didn't.

Did every step that suggested in the github issues:

- Change to base64.
- Changed relative path to absolute.
- png to jpg.

nothing helped

in the end - reinstall of the mpdf somehow solved it (not really sure why).
So if its helps anyone, try to reinstall using composer.

Answer (score 0):

simply do

```
<img src="<?php echo 'data:image/jpg;base64,'.base64_encode(file_get_contents('./template/assets/frontend/images/pdf-header.jpg')); ?>" style="width:100%;">
```